# Android App UI tab... is this UI possible?

Tags: android, user-interface

How can i implement this in a TabActivity?

[image]

Comment: Why is this layout special? A typical Android-Tab-UI looks like this:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/images/hello-tabwidget.png The only difference is the styling or the colors.

Comment: Ok...so i guess i will have to put one image as the application background and transaparent or opaque tab images on the tab activity right...

Comment: Yes, that would be the best solution. As android supports semi-transparance, this should not be very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks much like the standard TabHost ( http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html ) and an implementation of OnTabChangedListener.

Add the listener to the instance of your TabHost:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        setTabHostColors();
    }});
```

Handle changing the background color:

```
private void setTabHostColors() {
    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)); //unselected
    }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(50, 120, 160)); // selected
}
```

And then finally it obviously has a nice little background picture, not sure where to get that one I'm afraid.

Comment: Prior to 2.2 you can't actually change the drawable of the grey strip beneath the tabs (unless you use Reflection), so they're probably using either a custom TabHost implementation or simply a RadioGroup  for the tabs.

Comment: Cool..guess this should work.. Guess this reflection is something that might be a bit tough to implement...

Comment: Oh @Joseph, that's a good point, thanks! Well, if the strip below is so valuable, I guess Arun will have to implement a custom TabHost. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small sample project to customize your tabs: http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/